# org.eclipse.search.internal.ui.searchpreferencepage.java is not available on eclipse 3.7.2

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I could not find org.eclipse.search.internal.ui.searchpreferencepage.java in eclipse 3.7.2 version.It was available on eclipse 3.2.2. Can any one help me on finding that why this class has been removed from latest version and is there any alternative for this class on new version.

Is there any limit related methods on eclipse 3.7.2 plugins?

Comment: What are you using this internal page for?

Comment: Actually eclipse is embedded on our product and we are using this plugin to display logs in a table form

Comment: What are you doing with the preferences page?

Comment: We are using searchpreference.java for the following methods: getTableLimit() and isTableLimited().Is there any alternative for SearchPreference.java on eclipse 3.7.2?

Comment: Those methods are no longer present - see edited answer

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Is there any method/plugin can serve the same service on 3.7.2  as these methods are not available

Comment: I think the current search code simply does not have a limit anymore.

Comment: okay.. So you are about to tell that we have to implement our own classes for this and no other alternatives available on eclipse plugins

Comment: Found were the limit has moved to, see edited answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply.This solution may not appropriate for our requirements, because earlier we were using methods getTableLimit() method returns the limit

Comment: Hi Greg, Is there any other limit related methods on eclipse 3.7.2.If will be so helpful for me if I am getting those information, because even i need to use isTableLimited() also

Answer (score 1):

This is an internal class and consequently is not part of the Eclipse API and is subject to change without notice (see [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-API-Use/index.html)).

However it is still present in Eclipse 4.3 but is marked `x-internal:=true` in the `Export-Package` in the `MANIFEST.MF`. It is also present in Eclipse 3.8, in both cases in the `org.eclipse.search` plug-in.

The table limits which used to be in the preference page were removed some time ago, probably when the option to show the results in a tree was added.

Edit:

Further research shows the limit was moved from the preferences page to the `Search Filters` dialog in the drop down menu of the search view. The limit configured here can be accessed using the `getElementLimit()` method of `org.eclipse.search.ui.text.AbstractTextSearchViewPage`

`getElementLimit()` returns `null` if there is no limit.